# Поиск сообщений с отрицательным количеством голосов

Tags: поддержка, поиск

Хочу найти сообщения с отрицательным кол-вом голосов. Однако в справке по расширенному поиску параметр `score` задает либо минимальное кол-во, и в этом случае в результат попадают все сообщения с рейтингом `>=` заданного, либо вообще без голосов, если задано значение `0`.

Можно ли обеспечить поиск сообщений только с отрицательным кол-вом голосов?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Отвечу словами нашего современника @Nicolas Chabanovsky:

Мой любимый запрос: "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-1+created%3A1d"

тобишь

`score:..указанное число` (одна/две точки после двоеточия) равносилен `score <= указанное число`

`score:указанное число` (сразу число после двоеточия) равносилен `score >= указанное число`

---

В [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) написано, кстати:

*Диапазоны*

Для поиска сообщений попадающих в заданный диапазон голосов, количества ответов или просмотров, можно использовать верхнюю или нижнюю границу или обе одновременно.

- `score:-1` или `score:-1..` - выполняет поиск сообщений с оценкой превышающей или равной -1.
- `views:500..1000` или `views:500-1000` - выполняет поиск вопросов с количеством просмотров от 500 до 1000.
- `answers:..3` - выполняет поиск вопросов содержащих 3 и менее ответов.

Comment: Данный ответ может быть закрыт как дубликат справки :)

Comment: @alexolut собственно вопрос закрыть, как rtfm %)

Comment: Да. Надо ссылку на справку из расширенного поиска жирным выделить :) Или и вовсе добавить про диапазоны в советы.